# Saving datetime string to DateTimeField returns validation error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save this value `2013-05-01T00:00:00.000+02:00` to a `DateTimeField` in django, but I get a validation error on save.

What could be wrong?

Here is Model,

```
class Entry(models.Model):
            name = models.CharField(max_length=500, )  
            published = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

--

```
@task()
def import_entry_from_xml(data):
    #Import function 
    entry = Entry(name=values['name'])
    if hasattr(data, 'published'):
          entry.published = data['published'] #Returns 2013-05-01T00:00:00.000+02:00     
    entry.save()
```

Error:

`ValidationError: [u"'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]`

Comment: Give more information.  In the sample above it looks like you've combined your model with a code snippet that's calling it, and the indentation is confusing.  It would also be helpful if you shared the full content of the error you see, including traceback if available.

Comment: DateTimeField doesn't accept ISO 8601 formatted date string. Here is ticket for this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11385

Comment: @Fledgling - isn't that about the form field type, not the model field type? I admit I haven't checked lately whether the model field can autoconvert some string representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTimeField`s expect a Python `datetime` object, not a string. Use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to convert your string into a `datetime`.

The `hasattr` call is almost certainly wrong, too. If you want to see if `published` is in your `data` dictionary, use `if 'published' in data:`